# How to get NaN when I divide by zero

Tags: python

When I do floating point division in Python, if I divide by zero, I get an exception:

```
>>> 1.0/0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

I'd really like to get `NaN` or `Inf` instead (because the `NaN` or `Inf` will propagate through the rest of my calculation correctly and not kill my program).

How can I do this?

Comment: Is dividing by zero actually `NaN` or `Inf`?

Comment: @beerbajay: `0.0 / 0.0` —> `nan`, `1.0 / 0.0` —> `inf`, `-1.0 / 0.0` —> `-inf`.

Comment: Actually very interesting would be to change the Python behavior so it really works for `1.0 / 0` without explicitly retyping everything or putting try-except everywhere.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The easiest way to get this behaviour is to use `numpy.float64` instead of Python default `float` type:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.float64(1.0) / 0.0
inf
```

Of course this requires NumPy.  You can use [`numpy.seterr()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) to fine-tune the error handling.

Comment: This worked great. You can even pass `numpy.float64` values to SWIG-wrapped C libraries without any problems.

Comment: What's the point of even having `float('inf')` and `float('nan')` built in to Python if you have to use a 3rd-party library to get the expected behaviour? i.e., it seems like typing `float('inf')` explicitly is the only time I can actually count on seeing an 'inf' result returned by Python.

Comment: The first time you run this, it will throw an error.

Comment: @becko: It prints a warning, which is quite different from throwing an error.  You can control warnings using the built-in `warnings` module.

Comment: @Brandin E.g. `1e200 * 1e200` results in `inf`. But I agree, I would also like to either have IEEE 754 behavior all-round or no `inf` and `nan` at all.

Answer (score 28):

**Method 1:**

```
try:
    value = a/b
except ZeroDivisionError:
    value = float('Inf')
```

**Method 2:**

```
if b != 0:
    value = a / b
else:
    value = float('Inf')
```

But be aware that the value could as well be `-Inf`, so you should make a more distinctive test. Nevertheless, this above should give you the idea how to do it.

Comment: Oh! Somehow I thought this was a new question. Anyway, it's there as of version 3.5

Comment: @glglgl I've checked this and I get `inf`, `-inf` and ` ` anyone know why that might be the ZeroDivisionError is always raised?

Comment: Note: 0/0 == NaN; the result of a/b is +Inf or -Inf  if a != 0 and b == 0

Answer (score 10):

You could try using the 'decimal' module:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> setcontext(ExtendedContext)
>>> inf = Decimal(1) / Decimal(0)
>>> print(inf)
Infinity
>>> neginf = Decimal(-1) / Decimal(0)
>>> print(neginf)
-Infinity
>>> print(neginf + inf)
NaN
>>> print(neginf * inf)
-Infinity
>>> print(dig / 0)
Infinity
```

Answer (score -6):

If i understand your problem properly then this should be the solution:

```
try:
   1.0/0.0
except:    
   return 'inf'
```

you can modified it according to various python exception handling method available

Comment: Better `float('inf')` instead of `'inf'` - you'll get a float then, not a string...

Comment: Better `except ZeroDivisionError`, `except` alone also catches `KeyboardInterrupt` etc.

Answer (score -6):

I used a wrapper function in a python program of mine for a simple division that was returning ZeroDivisionError when the sensors I was using weren't plugged in. It simply returns 0 (zero), which in real-world terms is what I wanted. Probably gets messy with more variables, however...

```
def calculation(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return 0
    elif b == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return a/b
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to revise this for what was being asked, but all you have to do is change the zero's to "NaN" I believe.

Comment: This is not a general solution. E.g. I would not expect a / 0.0 to give 0, nor would I expect it to give NaN.