# divided by 0 and 0.00

Tags: javascript, python, ruby

Javascript

```
0/0       // NaN
0/0.0     // NaN
1/0.0     // Infinity
1/0.0     // Infinity
```

Ruby

```
>> 0/0     # ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
>> 0/0.00  # NaN
>> 1/0.00  # Infinity
>> -1/0.00 # -Infinity
```

Python

```
>>> 0/0    # ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> 0/0.0  # ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> 1/0.0  # ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> -1/0.0 # ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

What's the reason behind

Integers cannot be divided by zero, but float can be?

And in python, why it's not a NaN or Infinity, but all errors?

Comment: Different languages, different choices.

Comment: Why does the answer matter? As long as you know how the language your using works that should be enough shouldn't it?

Comment: All numbers in JavaScript are IEEE floats, hence *0 is the same as 0.0 in JavaScript*. Other languages may have a distinction between integers (that generally cannot represent NaN) and floats (which usually can).

Comment: why the need to divide by 0 anyways??

Comment: You can conclude that ZeroDivisionError from Python takes on different meanings in other languages. Try to define in Python your custom exceptions like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python

Comment: In Python, you can just say `x/y if y else float('inf')` if you want that behaviour

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get NaN when I divide by zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011707/how-to-get-nan-when-i-divide-by-zero)

Answer (score 3):

Floating point divide by zero *can* be an exception in many environments (if enabled) but since IEEE float has the ability to express some exceptional values (like `Inf`, `Nan`) it is also possible for division by zero to return an exceptional *value*, which integer operations cannot.

You are also observing different parsing (or promotion?) in different languages. However, a bare `0` in JavaScript *is* a floating point 0 rather than an integer zero.

Comment: does that mean python does not follow IEEE 754 standard?

Comment: @bighostkim Ask a question about Python and floating point division by 0.0: focus, focus, focus. (But better, search first - this is not a new question.)

Comment: The IEEE-754 standards allows returning special values or raising exceptions. Python chooses to use an exception for division by 0. The Decimal (included with Python) and gmpy2 (available separately) libraries uses contexts to allow the programmer to control when exceptions are raised.

Answer (score 2):

Different languages make different choices.

The case of Javascript is easy: integers are stored as floats and has chosen to follow [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) rules on division.

Python apparently forbids division by `0` or by `0.0`. See ways around this [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011707/how-to-get-nan-when-i-divide-by-zero).

Ruby makes the distinction between an exact `0` and a float like `0.0` (or `-0.0`). Indeed, `0.0` could stand for a very small positive number that can't be expressed within the precision of a floating point number (e.g. `0.1e-400`). It is in this view that `1/0.1e-400` returns `Float::INFINITY`, since `1e401` is too big to be represented with any other float.

Ruby actually has two different comparison operators to make that distinction:

```
0 == 0.0 # => true
0.eql?(0.0) # => false
```

This can have some important consequences:

```
h = {0 => :foo}
h[0.0] # => nil
```

Comment: [zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Zero) - aka 0.0 (and -0.0) - has an exact IEEE float representation ..

Comment: Also, the argument about the ruby equality just goes to show that `0` (fixnum) is not the same as `0.0` (Float) but does not say that they are (or are not) not numerically equal: they are.

Comment: @pst: `0.0` has a representation, but `0.1e-400` doesn't. As for equality, they are `==` but not `eql?`, which can be important. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

> And in python, why it's not a NaN or Infinity, but all errors?

Certain modules in python do have this, when they would be appropriate:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(3)

In [3]: b = np.ones(3)

In [4]: b/a
Out[4]: array([ inf,  1. ,  0.5])
```