# Avoiding "complex division by zero" error in Numpy (related to cmath)

Tags: python, numpy, divide-by-zero, cmath

I would like to avoid `ZeroDivisionError: complex division by zero` in my calculation, getting `nan` at that exception.

Let me lay out my question with a simple example:

```
from numpy import *
from cmath import *

def f(x) :
    x = float_(x) 
    return 1./(1.-x)

def g(x) :
    x = float_(x)
    return sqrt(-1.)/(1.-x)

f(1.)   # This gives 'inf'.
g(1.)   # This gives 'ZeroDivisionError: complex division by zero'.
```

It is my intention to get `g(1.) = nan`, or at least anything but an error that interrupts the calculation.
**First question: how can I do it?**

Importantly, I would **not** like to modify the code inside the functions (for example, inserting conditions for exceptions, as is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34664402/5471637)), but rather keep it in its current form (or even deleting the `x = float_(x)` line if possible, as I mention below).
The reason is that I am working with a long code with dozens of functions: I would like them all to avoid `ZeroDivisionError` without the need of making lots of changes.

I was forced to insert `x = float_(x)` to avoid a `ZeroDivisionError` in `f(1.)`.
**Second question:** would there be a way of suppressing this line but still get `f(1.) = inf` without modifying at all the code defining `f`?

---

EDIT:

I have realized that using `cmath` (`from cmath import *`) is responsible for the error.
Without it, I get `g(1.) = nan`, which is what I want.
However, I need it in my code.
So now the **first question** turns into the following: **how can I avoid "complex division by zero" when using `cmath`?**

---

EDIT 2:

After reading the answers, I have made some changes and I simplify the question, getting closer to the point:

```
import numpy as np                            
import cmath as cm                            

def g(x) :                                    
    x = np.float_(x)                         
    return cm.sqrt(x+1.)/(x-1.)    # I want 'g' to be defined in R-{1}, 
                                   # so I have to use 'cm.sqrt'. 

print 'g(1.) =', g(1.)             # This gives 'ZeroDivisionError: 
                                   # complex division by zero'.
```

**Question**: how can I avoid the `ZeroDivisionError` not modifying the code of my function `g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why you need to use cmath. Type-cast `x` into `np.complex_` when you expect complex output, and then use `np.sqrt`.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    x = np.float_(x)
    return 1. / (1. - x)

def g(x):
    x = np.complex_(x)
    return np.sqrt(x + 1.) / (x - 1.)
```

This yields:

```
>>> f(1.)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:3: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
Out[131]: inf

>>> g(-3.)
Out[132]: -0.35355339059327379j

>>> g(1.)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:3: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in cdouble_scalars
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:3: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cdouble_scalars
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
Out[133]: (inf+nan*j)
```

The drawback being, of course, that the function `g` will *always* end up giving you complex output, which could later cause problems if you feed its result back into `f`, for instance, because *that* now type-casts to float, and so on... Maybe you should just type-cast to complex everywhere. But this will depend on what you need to achieve on some bigger scale.

**EDIT**

It turns out that there's a way to get `g` to return complex only if it needs to be. Use [`numpy.emath`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.emath.html).

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    x = np.float_(x)
    return 1. / (1. - x)

def g(x):
    x = np.float_(x)
    return np.emath.sqrt(x + 1.) / (x - 1.)
```

This now gives what you would expect, converting to complex only when necessary.

```
>>> f(1)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
Out[1]: inf

>>> g(1)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:12: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
Out[2]: inf

>>> g(-3)
Out[3]: -0.35355339059327379j
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the function handled the errors by itself, but if not, then you could do it when you call the function (I do beleive this is more work than modifying the fnctions though).

```
try:
    f(1.)   # This gives 'inf'.
except ZeroDifivisionError:
    None    #Or whatever
try:
    g(1.)   # This gives 'ZeroDivisionError: complex division by zero'.
except ZeroDifivisionError:
    None    #Or whatever
```

Or, as the the answer you referred to tells, call your function with a numpy number:

```
f(np.float_(1.))
g(np.float_(1.))
```

=======
On my machine, this exact code gives me a warning and no error.
I don't think it's possible to get what you want without catching errors...

```
def f(x):
    return 1./(1.-x)

def g(x):
    return np.sqrt(-1.)/(1.-x)

print f(np.float_(1.))
>> __main__:2: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
>>inf

print g(np.float_(1.))
>> __main__:5: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
>>nan
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these options are not really what I am looking for. As you say, the first might involve more work than modifying the functions themselves. And notice that in the second alternative you give, `g(np.float_(1.))` does not work (my code already included `x = np.float_(x)` inside the definition of `g`, and that yielded the `ZeroDivisionError` I reported).

Comment: In my machine (W8.1, Python 2.7.10, Numpy 1.10.1) I get a warning and no error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my machine (Python 2.7.10), I get a **warning** if I do not include the line `from cmath import *`, but I get the **error** when I write it. I need that line in my code.
Please, notice also that my question is to get `nan` (or at least not an error) when inserting `g(1.)`, and not `g(numpy.float_(1.))` or any other alternative.
Is there a solution for what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because your program is using the `sqrt` function from the `cmath` library. This is a good example of why you should avoid (or at least be careful with) importing the entire library using `from library import *`.

For instance, if you reverse the import statements then you will have no problem:

```
from cmath import *
from numpy import *

def f(x):
    x = float_(x) 
    return 1./(1.-x)


def g(x) :
    x = float_(x)
    return sqrt(-1.)/(1.-x)
```

Now `g(1.)` returns `nan`, because the `sqrt` function of `numpy` is used (which can handle negative numbers). But that's still bad practice: if you have a large file, then it is not clear which `sqrt` is being used.

I recommend always using named imports such as `import numpy as np` and `import cmath as cm`. Then the function `sqrt` is not imported, and to define `g(x)` you need to write `np.sqrt` (or `cm.sqrt`).

However, you noted that you don't want to change your function. In that case you should only import those functions from each library that you need, i.e.

```
from cmath import sin  # plus whatever functions you are using in that file
from numpy import sqrt, float_

def f(x):
    x = float_(x) 
    return 1./(1.-x)


def g(x) :
    x = float_(x)
    return sqrt(-1.)/(1.-x)
```

Unfortunately, you cannot easily get rid of the conversion to numpy `float_`, because python floats are not the same as numpy floats so this conversion needs to take place at some point.

Comment: I think you got really close to the point. As you suggest, I import `cmath` and `numpy` as `cm` and `np`, respectively. However, I am still in trouble. I invite you to have a look at the second edit of my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to use the numpy sqrt function. So replace `cm.sqrt` by `np.sqrt`.

Comment: No, because as I say in the comments (inside the code), I want my function `g` to be defined for all x in R-{1}: if I use `np.sqrt`, I get `g(-3.) = nan`, and I would like to get `g(-3.) = (-0-0.333333333333j)`.